# Why cant the child div activate its scroll when the fixed parent div reaches its max-height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have this, which makes a fixed window above everything else, and has a max height of 80% of the screen height. Inside, it has a div that has information about someone and a couple of tabs in which each one has a table that shows the resources that that person used, which means that the number of elements in each table could be n number of rows.  Each tab fades out when you click them. The problem is that I wish that the content of the tabs could be scrolled when the parent div reaches its max height. But as you can see neither the outside scroll nor the inside one work. I have already been able to make it so that the parent div stops growing past its max height, but when I show the contents of one of the tabs, it grows past the parent div and doesn't activate the scroll.
It would be best if the inside scroll could be done so that I have the info of the person fixed, but if the only way to do this is with the outside one, then by all means help me with that one.

```js
function toggleR(object) {
  var Rinfo = object;
  var RArea = $(Rinfo).siblings("table");
  RArea.fadeToggle("slow");
}
```

```css
.RHInfo {
  position: fixed;
  left: 17.5%;
  right: 17.5%;
  z-index: 350;
  max-height: 77%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: inherit;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 99%;
  top: 5rem;
}

.RHInfolayout {
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: thin solid #929597;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.fpInfoArea {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: large;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-family: "Kelson bd";
  z-index: 15;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 11px 4px rgba(9, 9, 9, 1.00);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 11px 4px rgba(9, 9, 9, 1.00);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
  background-color: #929597;
  height: 1.75rem;
}

.red {
  background-color: #ED2625 !important;
}

.RHInfoContainer {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 1.75rem - 15px);
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.downby1 {
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
}

.hdivider {
  height: 2px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(203, 50, 50, 0.00) 0.52%, rgba(180, 49, 49, 0.50) 14.51%, rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.50) 52.33%, rgba(180, 49, 49, 0.50) 88.60%, rgba(203, 50, 50, 0.00) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(203, 50, 50, 0.00) 0.52%, rgba(180, 49, 49, 0.50) 14.51%, rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.50) 52.33%, rgba(180, 49, 49, 0.50) 88.60%, rgba(203, 50, 50, 0.00) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(203, 50, 50, 0.00) 0.52%, rgba(180, 49, 49, 0.50) 14.51%, rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.50) 52.33%, rgba(180, 49, 49, 0.50) 88.60%, rgba(203, 50, 50, 0.00) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(203, 50, 50, 0.00) 0.52%, rgba(180, 49, 49, 0.50) 14.51%, rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.50) 52.33%, rgba(180, 49, 49, 0.50) 88.60%, rgba(203, 50, 50, 0.00) 100%);
}

.RHInfoContainer #ResourcesArea {
  flex: 1;
  max-height: 90%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.slimtable tr th {
  padding-top: 0.1rem;
  background-color: #d32f2f;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: small;
  padding-bottom: 0.1rem;
  border: thick solid #f44336;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slimtable tr td {
  background-color: #464141;
  border: thin solid #232323;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 0.3rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.4rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="RHInfocard" class="RHInfo">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 RHInfolayout white col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-lg-12 fpInfoArea red">
      <div>INFORMACIÓN DEL RECURSO HUMANO EN EL
        <div id="IdFP">&nbsp;FP1418</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 RHInfoContainer">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="InfoRH" class="col-lg-12 downby1">
          <div id="RHBajaButton" class="col-lg-10 downby2 col-md-10 col-sm-9"><button class="BajaButton btn red white-text right">BAJA</button></div>
          <div id="RHNombre" class="col-lg-10 downby1 pdownby1 col-md-10 col-sm-9">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4">Nombre:</div>
            <div id="nombre" class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="RHPuesto" class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-9">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-8">Función(es) en el proyecto:</div>
            <div id="puesto" class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-4"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 downby1 pdownby1 col-md-offset-0 col-md-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-12">
          <div class="hdivider"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="ResourcesArea" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="col-lg-12 fpInfoArea red col-md-12 col-sm-12" onClick="toggleR(this);">RECURSOS TECNICOS UTILIZADOS</div>
          <table class="slimtable">
            <tbody id="listaRT">
              <tr>
                <th style="width: 10%" scope="col" class="center"><i class="fi-rt-circ white-text"></i></th>
                <th scope="col">Nombre del Recurso Tecnico</th>
                <th style="width: 25%" scope="col">Tiempo de Uso</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <br>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="col-lg-12 fpInfoArea red col-md-12 col-sm-12" onClick="toggleR(this);">RECURSOS MATERIALES UTILIZADOS</div>
          <table class="slimtable">
            <tbody id="listaRM">
              <tr>
                <th style="width: 10%" scope="col" class="center"><i class="fi-rm-circ white-text"></i></th>
                <th scope="col">Nombre del Recurso Material</th>
                <th style="width: 25%" scope="col">Cantidad Utilizada</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
                <td>iedjfi</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Your parent `div` has `position:fixed`. In order for this to work you need both the parent `div` and the scroll-able `div` to have declared heights or `.RHInfolayout, .RHInfoContainer {height:100%}` https://jsfiddle.net/02jnk6sf/ - **Sidenote:** Your code is not responsive. And there are a couple of elements with unnecessary `overflow` properties. Also, if you use `overflow-y: auto` the scroll bar won't show up unless it's needed.

Comment: Yes, I know about all the unnecessary overflows, its just that I was checking if any of it was affecting the divs that I needed to work.

Comment: @Ihazkode The problem is that by doing so the parent div is set to have the desired height even though maybe the information inside could be much less of that.